# How to plot an imaginary number, i, power tower as done in the following way?

Tags: plotting, functions, complex, iterators, iteration

Can somebody explain what two variables exactly they have plotted against each other to get such graphs, and how one would go about getting this graph in Mathematica?

[image]

Answer (score 14):

- Plot the left graph.

```
pts = RecurrenceTable[{q[n + 1] == I^q[n], q[1] == I}, 
   q[n], {n, 1, 50}];
ComplexListPlot[pts, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

- Solved the limit point.

```
NSolve[Q == I^Q, Q]
Reduce[Q == I^Q, Q] /. C[1] -> 0 // N
```

```
sol = NSolve[{θ*Tan[θ] == 
    Log[π/2*Cos[θ]/θ], 0 <= θ <= 2 π}, 
  Reals]
2/π*θ/Cos[θ]*Exp[I*θ] /. sol
```

[image]

- Partition the points to three groups to view the spiral like.

```
ComplexListPlot[Transpose@Partition[pts, 3], Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Magenta, Red}, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Exact solving works fine: `Solve[Q == I^Q, Q]` gives `2*I*ProductLog[-I*π/2]/π` (even getting the correct branch of the Lambert $W$ function for once!)

Answer (score 8):

Plotting the real part on the horizontal and the imaginary part on the vertical axis, as is common:

```
Q = SolveValues[I^q == q, q];
ComplexListPlot[NestList[I^# &, I, 100], Joined -> True, 
                PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
                PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
                Frame -> True,
                GridLines -> Transpose[ReIm[Q]]]
```

[image]

Thanks to @cvgmt for pointing out the use of [`ComplexListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexListPlot.html)!

For the spiral: we note that for a point $q$ close to the asymptotic point $Q=\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n=\frac{2i}{\pi} W\left(-\frac{i\pi}{2}\right)$ the transformation $q\to i^q$ is well approximated by
$$
i^q\approx Q+p (q-Q)
$$
with $p=-W\left(-\frac{i\pi}{2}\right)$. In Mathematica,

```
f[q_] = I^q;
p = -ProductLog[-I*π/2];
Q = -2*I*p/π;
Series[f[q] - (Q + p*(q - Q)), {q, Q, 1}]
(*    O[q-Q]^2    *)
```

In this sense, the numbers $q_n$ for large $n$ are well described by
$$
q_n \approx Q + \zeta p^n
$$
with the constant $\zeta$ to be determined. I don't have a closed-form expression for $\zeta$, but rather find it experimentally (approximately) with

```
$MaxExtraPrecision = 10^3;
$RecursionLimit = ∞;
ζ = With[{n = 1000}, N[(Nest[f, 1, n] - Q)/p^n, 10^3]];
N[ζ]
(*    0.638834 - 0.258313 I    *)
```

With these approximations we can now plot the spirals:

```
p3 = -(-1)^(1/3) p;
colors = {Blue, Darker@Green, Red};
ParametricPlot[{ReIm[Q + ζ p p3^n],
                ReIm[Q + ζ p^2 p3^n],
                ReIm[Q + ζ p3^n]},
               {n, 1, 100}, PlotRange -> All, 
               PlotStyle -> colors,
               GridLines -> Transpose[ReIm[{Q}]], 
               Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], 
                 Transpose[{colors, 
                 Point /@ Transpose[Partition[ReIm[NestList[f, I, 99]], 3]]}]},
               Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I just saw the above answer. But since I already wrote this might as well post it.

The spiral one is tricky. This is for the left side one only

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
q[n_ /; n == 1] := I
q[n_ /; n == 2] := Exp[-Pi/2]
q[n_] := I^q[n - 1];
data = Table[{Re[q[n]], Im[q[n]]}, {n, 1, 30}];
ListLinePlot[data,  Mesh -> All, 
 PlotRange -> All, MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[.015]}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]